# How to open New activity on click on Button in Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is my `ActionBar`, it has two buttons:

[image: My <code>ActionBar</code>]

```
private void showActionBar() {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_actions, null);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
}
```

I used this method to show buttons. I called this method in onCreate.

Now i want when i click on Any button which is in action bar New activity open.

For example i have AskActivity.java and MessageActivity.java

now when i click on ASK button AskActivity.java opens.

Is this possible?

I have used this but its not working.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_ask:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AskActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_message:
        Intent ij = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(ij);
        return true;

default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat or error

Comment: getting no error. Just unable to open AskActivity.class on Button click

Comment: Yeah you said that previously. So why don't you put Log.d or some thing to trace out what actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the `onOptionsItemSelected` method is related to `MenuItem` and not the `CustomView`. The two buttons **are not option menu items**, they are buttons inside the layout `activity_main_actions`. You have two choices - either create a new on click listener, as follows:

```
Button action_ask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_ask); 
action_ask.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         // do something
    }
}
```

Or, use the on click attribute method:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_ask"
    ...
    android:onClick="actionAskClicked" />
```

And then inside your Activity:

```
public void actionAskClicked() {
    // do something
}
```

Same for the other button `action_message`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a method to open an activity from menu button click:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 // Take appropriate action for each action item click
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
 case R.id.action_ask:

    startActivity(AskActivity.class);
    return true;
 default:
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}

 protected void StartActivity(Class<?> cls) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, cls);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
 }
```